# i want to upadate the password through a alert dialog by setting user timings?

Tags: android, android-notifications

i want to update the password  through a alert dialog by setting user timings?suppose i want to set the time after 1miniute, After 1 minute i want to reset the passsword  through alert,how can send the notification after time when app is open.[image]